# Algorithm and general pseudocode to greatly cut down on the space that a char permutation takes up

Tags: algorithm, storage, permutation, brute-force, fuzzing

Setting up a home web server on a Raspberry Pi as an education project, and I had the idea to run a URL fuzzing algorithm on it to test for vulnerabilities.

I decided on testing strings up to 32 characters long that use a set of 65 characters: letters a-z, letters A-Z, numbers 0-9, and '-', '_', and '.'

Assuming these would be stored in an ASCII-encoded .txt file wherein each character takes up 1 byte of storage, doing the math for the amount of storage I'd need optimally 20PB to store everything, which would obviously cost A LOT of money... just not feasible.

So, is there a kind of algorithm that can greatly reduce the space that this kind of thing takes up? Or am I able to just generate one string at a time, use it, and then discard it?

Did the calculation of the permutations and got an absurdly high number.

Comment: Like [Lempel-Ziv-Walch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch), implemented _eg_ [minizip](https://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html).

Answer (score 0):

Storing a large number of things takes a lot of space.  Generating it takes a lot of time. The only realistic solution is figuring out how to generate a useful subset of the things that can be done with reasonable space and reasonable time.